# New LED flood lights give off quick flash when turned off

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I just purchased 6 new LED Flood Lights for my kitchen, my kitchen has two light switches that turn the lights off and on and neither of them are dimmers so I purchased non dimmable LED lights.

One thing I've noticed and this doesn't happen every time but on ocassion when I turn the lights off they will provide a flicker once I hit the switch, I was wondering what is the cause of this and will it cause damage to the LED bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the LED driver inside of your flood lamp enclosure discharging any charge that is left in its circuitry. I couldn't imagine this being in issue, especially is its a very short flash

Comment: I have a similar issue with a light fixture that flashes once when the lights are turned on. Happens with every LED bulb I've put in the fixture. Is it common for LEDs to do this as well?